# Is this concurrent code slower because of overhead? or is something else at play?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm playing around with trying to build a arraylist class that is made threadsafe in a very clumsy way by just slapping on the synchronized keyword on all methods

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class LongArrayListUnsafe {
public static void main(String[] args) {
LongArrayList dal1 = LongArrayList.withElements();

ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      dal1.add(i);
  }
 });}
System.out.println("Using toString(): " + dal1);


for (int i=0; i<dal1.size(); i++)
  System.out.println(dal1.get(i));

System.out.println(dal1.size());} }

class LongArrayList {

private long[] items;
private int size;

public LongArrayList() {
   reset();
}

synchronized public static LongArrayList withElements(long... initialValues){
   LongArrayList list = new LongArrayList();
   for (long l : initialValues) list.add( l );
   return list;
}

// reset me to initial 
synchronized public void reset(){
  items = new long[2];
  size = 0;
}

// Number of items in the double list
synchronized public int size() {
  return size;
}

// Return item number i
synchronized public long get(int i) {
  if (0 <= i && i < size) 
   return items[i];
  else 
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.valueOf(i));
   }

   // Replace item number i, if any, with x
   synchronized public long set(int i, long x) {
   if (0 <= i && i < size) {
    long old = items[i];
    items[i] = x;
    return old;
   } else 
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.valueOf(i));}

   // Add item x to end of list
   synchronized public LongArrayList add(long x) {
   if (size == items.length) {
   long[] newItems = new long[items.length * 2];
   for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
       newItems[i] = items[i];
  items = newItems;
}
items[size] = x;
size++;
return this;
}

synchronized public String toString() {
  return Arrays.stream(items, 0,size)
  .mapToObj( Long::toString )
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
}
```

The relevant thing I'm doing is adding a bunch elements to a list, with some tasks.  The issue is that when I increase the amount of threads that I pass to the fixedthreadPool, my code runs in the same time as when I only pass only one thread, maybe even slower.
I have three theories on why this is:

- This is because of thread overhead, and the tasks I am creating are simply too small, I need to make them bigger before it pays off to use more threads.
- It has to do with lock contention, because my class is so clumsily threadsafe, the threads a are competing for the locks, and somehow slowing down everything
- I'm making a completely obvious mistake in using the threadexecutorpool

Comment: Both #1 and #2 are correct.

Comment: thought so, do you think it would make any sense to up the amount of add() that is performed in every task, or should I find a more complex operation to do?

Comment: There is not much possibility of using parallelism to create any speedup at all here.  You may have noticed that Java doesn't actually provide a thread-safe list that is any smarter than what you do here.

Comment: Also, is it generally not possible to achieve any speedup with the locking strategy that I have in this code?

Comment: That's correct.  (In this particular case, there may not be any locking strategy at all that improves meaningfully on the sequential approach.)

Comment: well the overall assignment that I have, is to implement a version of this class that reduces lock contention as much as possible.
I think I will probably have to test this with some of the less atomic methods of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not **only** that your task is to simple.  The key issue is that you marked the `add` function is synchronized which means that only a single thread is allowed to enter this function.  No matter how many executers you use, at any single point in time, there is only one thread executing this function, while the others have to wait.  Even if you make the task more complex, it won't change.  You need to have a more complex task and a more fine grained synchronization thereof.

As for lock contention.  Yes, see above, and of course acquiring and releasing locks costs time.

To answer the question in the comments:

- sychronized synchronizes on the object on which you invoke the class, (i.e., `dal1` which is shared by all your threads).
- yes, the contention is fairly obvious.  You said yourself "just slapping". Nevertheless for the code you have I would call it adequate.  The operation that takes the longest is resizing and copying of the array and during that time you certainly do not want any other thread to modify your array.

Comment: hmm, makes sense. The only thing is: doesnt add() need to be synchronized on the object? having mulitple threads accessing add at the same time would be a very obvious source of race conditions?

Comment: Hi again, I really hope you have the time for giving me a hint, your former answers were super helpfull. Do you think it will be possible to finegrain my add-method in any way?
I tried using read/write locks, but it fails:

Comment: You could do read/write locks.  This would help if you both write to and read from the array at the same time.  For instance, while enlarging/copying the array other requests could still read elements from the array.  And only when all the elements are copied, the add function would put a write lock on the array.  Whether that makes sense very much depends on your application and how often the application is indeed resizing the array.  For instance, if you can determine upfront how many elements to reserve, there would be little benefit if at all.